# How can upload metadata json to IPFS by javascript codes and how can programatically mint this URL by frontend

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I have started studying how to mint an NFT using solidity and IPFS.

The project flow is:

1. Install IPFS
2. Upload asset photo by IPFS and get its hash
3. Create a `metadata.json` file using the above hash

```
{
  "name": "NFT",
  "description": "This image shows the true nature of NFT.",
  "image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUnMkaEB5FBMDhjPsEtLyHr4ShSAoHUrwqVryCeuMosNr"
}
```

4: Upload this json file to IPFS and get its hash url

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmNSKewexhgY4rYwPoxPgNFN7BSjeiLXJif9q5FjeCrsmg
```

5: Create a `solidity` smart contract with a minting function. Deploy this using Polygon Mumbai network (using MATIC token).

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
 
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";
 
contract newNFT is NFTokenMetadata, Ownable {
  constructor() {
    nftName = "Synth NFT";
    nftSymbol = "SYN";
  }

  function mint(address _to, uint256 _tokenId, string calldata _uri) external onlyOwner {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
    super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
  }
}
```

6: After deploying the smart contract, the NFT is minted.

[image: MINT]

7. Go to OpenSea testnet, chose Mumbai testnet, and insert the address of the NFT owner.
8. Finally see the NFT on the testnet collection.

But I want to do this programatically in JavaScript, ReactJS and web3 library. How to achieve this?

Comment: the ipfs documentation has an example of how to do this.  https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/mint-nfts-with-ipfs/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this in javascript.
If you want to do it all on a single file, first you need to deploy your files to IPFS. I recommend using one of the few existing APIs to make it easier, such as Moralis, Nft.storage or Piñata.

With NFT.storage, you can do something like this to deploy to IPFS:

```js
const names = [
  "Test nft 1",
  "Test nft 2"
];

async function storeImage() {
  const content = await fs.readFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "../images/owl_articles.png")
  );

  const promisesToAwait: Promise<any>[] = [];

  names.forEach((name) => {
    promisesToAwait.push(
      client.store({
        name,
        description: `At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos.`,
        image: new File([content], "owl_articles.png", { type: "image/*" }),
      })
    );
  });

  const responses = await Promise.all(promisesToAwait);
  console.log(responses);
}

async function main() {
  await storeImage();
}

main();
```

The peice of code above will deploy an array of json files to IPFS, given the array `names`. They all have the same `image` and `description` for the sake of simplicity of the example.

In moralis, you can do something similar:

```js
const jsonFile = new Moralis.File('file.json', {
        base64: btoa(JSON.stringify({ name, description, image: imageURL }))
});
```

The code above will also deploy to ipfs, but in a different way.
I don't know why right now, but while this Moralis approach deploys it with `ipfs://{hash}` NFt.storage approach deploys it as `ipfs://{hash}/metadata.json`.

Anyway, after you use any of the processes above, you have to mint your NFT passing the URI as a param.

Using moralis, you can do it like this:

```js
      const jsonIpfsLink = `ipfs://${(jsonFile as any).hash()}/metadata.json`;

      await Moralis.Web3.executeFunction({
        ...options,
        functionName: 'create',
        params: {
          _initialSupply: '10',
          _uri: jsonIpfsLink
        }
      });
```

The code above is calling the method `create`from my ERC1155 contract. The contract method is shown below:

```js
    /**
     * @dev Creates a new token type and assigns _initialSupply msg.sender address
     * @param _initialSupply amount to supply the first owner
     * @param _uri URI for this token
     */
    function create(uint256 _initialSupply, string memory _uri) public {
        _uris[lastId.current()] = _uri;
        creators[lastId.current()] = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, lastId.current(), _initialSupply, "");
        emit ArticleMinted(msg.sender, _uri, lastId.current(), _initialSupply);
        lastId.increment();
    }
```

My example uses ERC1155 pattern, but it should be very similar on ERC721 pattern. It looks like you are using neither of them in your contract, but I strongly advise you to.
Also, Moralis would make your life easier. I would suggest using it in your front-end project.

I'm making a NFT marketplace and I use pretty much the code above to deploy to IPFS and mint right after.